# UIButton image. Auto size to real image size. Device based

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I have a universal application.

I have a main menu with 2 buttons.  The button have a  different size\shape on ipad and on iphone.

btn_main_all@2x~ipad.png
btn_main_all.png

I'm using xcode filename to get the good image from each device(work great).  But the image are not resized to the good specific size.  (i've try each combinaison in storyboard... top left, fit..., etc.

How can I have the button to get the real image size ?

Comment: normally you should select in Xcode only the regular basic image name `btn_main_all.png`. Xcode will take care of choosing the correct image on different devices. The image will have the same visual size on every display, but in higher resolution. Or are you trying to achieve something different?

Comment: You can adjust constraints for different size classes to set up different bounds for different devices